# Downloading an image from an http website in Xamarin with C#

Tags: c#, ios, http, https, xamarin

I know how to download an image from a website with the `https` protocol:

```
static UIImage FromUrl (string uri)
{
    using (var url = new NSUrl (uri))
    using (var data = NSData.FromUrl (url))
        return UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
}
```

but when `uri` isn't an `https` website `data` becomes null.
Is there a workaround for this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if uri starts with `http://www.`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's specifically an issue with sites being served over insecure HTTP, then it's probably due to [App Transport Security](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/), which by default blocks connections to non-HTTPS sites. You can either whitelist specific sites which you need to reach over HTTP, or disable ATS entirely if necessary, using settings in `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the help. Disabling ATS in the plist worked like a charm.